# All Strings of {A,C,T,G}

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm currently working on a problem of solving the combination of the different length of {A,C,T,G}, from 1 letter to 6 letters.
For example:

```
------#=1------
1:A
2:C
3:G
4:T
------#=2------
1:AA
2:AC
3:AG
4:AT
5:CA
6:CC
7:CG
8:CT
9:GA
10:GC
11:GG
12:GT
13:TA
14:TC
15:TG
16:TT
------#=3------
1:AAA
2:AAC
3:AAG
4:AAT
5:ACA
.
.
.
```

Now I can only solve the combinations from 1 to 4 letters, and I have no idea how to solve the combination of {A,C,T,G} of 5 letters and 6 letters, which the length of the combination(5 and 6) is greater than the length of all the strings(4)....

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


void combinationUtil(char arr[], char data[], int start, int end, int index, int r);
void printCombination(char arr[], int n, int r)
{
    char data[100];
    combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r);
}

void combinationUtil(char arr[], char data[], int start, int end, int index, int r)
{
    if (index == r) {
        for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
            cout << data[j];
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }

    for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
    {
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
    }
}


int main()
{
    char arr[] = {'A','T','C','G'};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    printCombination(arr, n, 1);
    printCombination(arr, n, 2);
    printCombination(arr, n, 3);
    printCombination(arr, n, 4);
    printCombination(arr, n, 5);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use 5 or 6? I don't want to have to compile and run your code to find out.

Comment: your code assumes each letter can only occur once in each sequence.  That's why with `2` you only get 6 combinations instead of, say, 16.  So what are you expecting to get with `5`?  It's impossible.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez Sorry for the miss information Brian....nothing shows up on the screen when I use 5 and 6

Comment: why do you need this condition => '&& end-i+1 >= r-index' in for loop. Only role of variable 'r' should be to control the depth of recursion stack which you are already doing by incrementing 'index' . when index reaches 'r' it hits the base condition and return.  Therefore try this => for (int i=start; i<=end; i++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least assuming I understand what you want, this is pretty easy to solve by treating it as counting from 0 to some limit in base 4, with the "digits" displayed as "A", "C", "G" and "T".

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string cvt(unsigned input, unsigned len) { 
    std::string ret;
    static const char letters[] = "ACGT";

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        ret.push_back(letters[input%4]);
        input /= 4;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    unsigned limit = 1;
    unsigned length = 4;

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        limit *= 4;

    for (int i=0; i<limit; i++)
        std::cout << cvt(i, length) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: But I am not quite understand what's your limit for??

Comment: @mattNest: `limit` is just computing how many possibilities there are for N "digits". And um...linked list? Really. At least at first blush, that sounds to me like nearly the worst possibility I can imagine for the job.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks Jerry, it  really helps

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes each letter can only be used once.  That's why you are getting no results for both sequences of length 5 and 6.  Rewrite your function as the following and do not pass as `start` or `end` value to it:

```
void combinationUtil(char arr[], char data[], int index, int r)
{

    if (index == r)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<r; ++j)
            cout << data[j];

        cout << endl;
        return;
    }


    for (int i=0; i<r; ++i)
    {
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, index+1, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helps!!